# A Way To Merge Differences Between Two Strings?

Tags: php, wordpress, html-parsing, string-parsing

I've created a wordpress plugin which automatically adds a `<!--more-->` tag to your post based on certain criteria, but intelligently places this tag inside your post. The problem is, I haven't come up with a proper way to battle HTML code. Currently I have it checking to see if there is a `<`, and if so, it finds the next `>` in the post.

What I'm hoping to do here is remove the html from the equation entirely. I was wondering if there is any system, like a git for PHP, where I would be able to save the HTML code version of the string, and then strip the HTML away and store the plaintext version of the code in another variable, place the `<!--more-->` tag into the plaintext version of the code, and then compare the two versions to properly merge the HTML code back into the plaintext.

I've tried Google, I've done about 100 hours of code changes, and I've still not come up with a solution. So now I'm bowing to the power of the cloud. Is there anyone here that can come up with a solution?

Comment: where are you placing the `<!--more-->`? `strip_tags()` will deal with removing the HTML tags for you.

Comment: It's placed based on a few variables. These could be character count or percentage of the post,location of the nearest space or end line character, and I'm also working on a word count system. The issue isn't so much the placement of the tag, so much as the removal of the HTML and then re-addition of the HTML in the same location.

Comment: Yes, I can remove the tags easily enough, but I need to preserve the tags, as they are essential aspects of the posts.

Comment: Can you not store a version that is run through `htmlentities()` in the db. Then just recall it with `html_entity_decode()`?

Comment: The problem still remains that I run the risk of the tag being placed inside the HTML code, and destroying it. I'm looking for a system that would take: `<p style="text-align: justify;">text goes here</p>` turn it into: `text goes here` add the tag like: `text goes here<!--more-->` and then merge it to become `<p style="text-align: justify;">text goes here<!--more--></p>`

Comment: All of this I can do. I'm looking for the merging aspect of it. I need to be able to compare the two variables and merge them properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have only a very rough idea of what you're trying to implement, so here's a very crude way of doing it.

Instead of taking the plain text separately and then doing all the calculations on it, you can do this in an "on the go" method.

Run a loop on all the characters in your post. If you find a `<` ignore ("continue") whatever comes next till you find a `>` so, essentially you get the plain text inside the loop, you can do all your initial counting inside this loop (total no. of character, no. of words, etc.) - Run this loop once more and add the more tag to the content based on the initial count, break out of the second loop.

Written below is another idea, which is a lot more complicated and assuming that you can't do without getting the plain text.

Let the M be the main string that contains the whole post content. Every time you find a `<tag>`, push it into an array, remember the location of this tag in M, push that into another array.

Once you have pushed all the tags in M into an array along with the location of the tag, what you have left is plain text. After you're done, pop back all the tags from the array to the plain text based on the location. This ofcourse, needs a lot of refinement, but its just an idea you can develop on.

Comment: The first option did the trick. It's a tiny bit resource intensive, but given the constraints I'm trying to limit myself to, it works like a dream. I did it a bit differently, instead of checking for `<` and `>` which can be legitimate parts of the post, I instead looked for differences between the stripped and unstripped.

Comment: And, as a bonus, this also helped me figure out how to do another aspect of this code that I had been stumbling over. I'd +1 you again for that, but I can't.